# How to access local environment of Blazor (wasm) on mobile?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I tried to access local env. of Blazor on mobile in several times but every efforts that I did wasn't worked.

I've set up the inbound & outbound settings => it doesn't work.
I've turned off the firewall => it also doesn't work.

I've tried to install `Keyoti.Conveyor.vsix`, but its version is not matched with my Windows version, so I can't install it.

Do I have to build the reverse proxy server on my computer just for testing? or is there any solutions to solve this problem?

Please let me know how I can solve this problem.

Comment: i mean localhost.